# How to compile TypeScript web app with node modules into one JavaScript file using CLI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, web-applications, node-modules

What is the simplest and fastest way to set up a TypeScript web application with node modules, that compiles into one JavaScript file that can be called from HTML?

For example, if I have the following project structure:

```
├── node_modules
│   └── mathjs
│   └── (dependencies, etc.)
├── public
│   └── index.html
│   └── app.js
├── src
│   └── app.ts
├── package-lock.json
└── package.json
```

`app.ts` contains the following code with node modules and typing imports:

```
import math from "mathjs";
import { Matrix } from "mathjs";

const point: Matrix = math.matrix([ +1, +1, +1 ]);
// etc...
```

How can I make it so that `app.ts` and all its dependencies are compiled into a single file `app.js` in the `public` directory such that, it can be included at the bottom of the `body` tag in `index.html` and be run in a browser?

```html
<script type="module" src="/app.js"></script>
```

In other words, what CLI tools can I use to compile this project for the web?

I have spent hours trying to research and get something to work (without copying and pasting directly from `node_modules`) and have not been able to get anything to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Edit: [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: how about using webpack? https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you could do using only the typescript compiler is to use system or amd modules inside the `tsconfig.json` and also use the `outFile` (this option works only with system or amd modules) option in order to concatenate all the files of your app into a bundle that you can use later with something like [system.js](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs). You can read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-8.html#concatenate-amd-and-system-modules-with---outfile).

I just want to note that with the standard tsconfig configuration the node_module dependencies won't be included inside the `outFile` config option bundle and you will have to configure `systemJS` to load them when separately. Maybe it is possible to include them as well but I haven't played around with the tsc options to achieve something like that, but you can try. Please do let me know if you succeed.

Btw if you decide to go with this approach and not use an external module bundler like webpack or rollup I suggest that you don't use the `outFile` option to bundle everything into one file because sometime ago I was struggling to make `systemJS` work with the out bundle but when I used separate files everything was working just fine.